# Why implement two interfaces that already extend each other?

Tags: php, spl, arrayobject, arrayiterator

I am trying to understand something about [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) and [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) classes

**`ArrayObject`**: This class implements the [`IteratorAggregate`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) and [`Traversable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interfaces. Since `IteratorAggregate` extends `Traversable` itself, why does `ArrayObject` implement both when it can just implement `IteratorAggregate`?

**`ArrayIterator`**: As above, this class implements both [`Iterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) and `Traversable` which `Iterator` extends.

Why do these classes implement two interfaces when they could get away with implementing the one that extends `Traversable`?

Comment: I suspect those links are only there to make the manual clearer and more *traversable* (ha) - ironically in your case that seems to have had the total opposite effect. I think you are correct in that one would more correctly say that they implement the `IteratorAggregate` and `Iterator` interfaces respectively.

Comment: ...although [it would seem](http://codepad.viper-7.com/r4FfNY) that you can write your code in this seemingly conflicting way and PHP will not complain about it.

Comment: I don't think Java would complain either but haven't tested it. It's like declaring unchecked exceptions: superfluous but not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SPL source code](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/spl_8php-source.html), ArrayObject doesn't implement `Traversable` directly:

```
class ArrayObject implements IteratorAggregate, ArrayAccess, Countable
{
    ...
}
```

This matches the [SPL documentation](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/main.html). I believe DaveRandom is correct.

Comment: I looked at the link and it looks like ArrayObject and ArrayIterator Classes both is not implements Traversable Interface directly,